# "Se te debería ir" vs. "Debería írsete"

Tags: verbos, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

Estaba escribiéndole a un amigo que acaba de ser operado, y redacté la siguiente frase.

> "En poco tiempo se te debería ir el dolor."

Sin embargo, suelo expresarme de otra forma. Lo que quise escribir, en realidad, fue lo siguiente:

> "En poco tiempo debería *írsete* el dolor"

¿Es esto correcto? Si no lo es, ¿cuál es la forma correcta de añadir los objetos correspondientes al verbo?

Comment: No me suena correcto. Pondría solamente *En poco tiempo debería irse el dolor*, sin necesidad de añadir el *-te*.

Comment: Es correcto, pero suena un poco forzado. En general es mejor evitar la concatenación de varios clíticos para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: @fedorqui Creo que eso es subjetivo. Como digo en mi respuesta, a mí no me suena forzado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las reglas de colocación de clíticos permiten ambas formas. Las dos frases son correctas y perfectamente intercambiables.

Mira [el punto 3.d del artículo sobre los pronombres personales átonos del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF):

Como hablante de España, debo decir también que las dos formas no solo son posibles según las reglas gramaticales, sino que ambas me resultan familiares y podría usarlas en cualquier momento (es decir, que para mí ninguna de las dos formas me "suena mejor").

Comment: +1   
 
La respuesta, en el mismo tono suéname arcaica: "Efectivamente, fuéseme el dolor al poco tiempo"

Comment: @belisarius Lo es, y posiblemente de parodiar el estilo me haya surgído esa costumbre. Nunca habría pensado que hoy estaría aprendiendo sobre el mismo idioma que hablo sólo por eso. Pero aquí estamos. :)

Chewie, muchas gracias, muy buena respuesta, agradezco más aún agregar la fuente del DPD.

Comment: @belisarius A mí esa forma también suéname arcaica, pero no paréceme tal cuando el verbo va en infinitivo.

Comment: Por ejemplo, «cójomela con papel de fumar» suena antiguo, pero no así «voy a cogérmela con papel de fumar» ;-)

Comment: A mi, _"fuéseme el dolor"_ lo que me suena es a asturiano.

Comment: @deStrangis Eso sería "acabóseme la sidra" :)